# How to run a custom function when starting an Erlang shell / node? (That is, a function within an `.erl` file)

Tags: bash, command-line, erlang, erlang-shell

I can start an Erlang file either via the command line or bash script:

```
exec erl file.erl
```

But, I cannot seem to find out how to directly start a function within this file.

e.g.

```
exec erl file.erl -f function()
```

Any suggestions appreciated...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

what you probably want is `erl -s module_name function_name`

Note that you never specify the erlang file in the erl command like you did there in your example. The Erlang VM loads all modules in the codepath. That includes local directory.

From http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html:

> **-run Mod [Func [Arg1, Arg2, ...]]**
>   (init flag) Makes init call the specified
>   function. Func defaults to start. If
>   no arguments are provided, the
>   function is assumed to be of arity 0.
>   Otherwise it is assumed to be of arity
>   1, taking the list [Arg1,Arg2,...] as
>   argument. All arguments are passed as
>   strings. See init(3).
>
> **-s Mod [Func [Arg1, Arg2, ...]]**
>   (init flag) Makes init call the specified
>   function. Func defaults to start. If
>   no arguments are provided, the
>   function is assumed to be of arity 0.
>   Otherwise it is assumed to be of arity
>   1, taking the list [Arg1,Arg2,...] as
>   argument. All arguments are passed as
>   atoms. See init(3).

Comment: Thanks Jon!  As always, you pull through  :)

Comment: Also. If you are making a command line tool check out escript. It's a pretty nice tool to have in the war chest.  http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html

Comment: There is also `-eval` in case you need to start that function with an argument other than a list of strings or atoms. Oh, and you might want to add `-noshell` to prevent the interactive shell from opening, and possibly add `-s init stop` at the end to actually quit Erlang when the function is done.

Comment: jon and ndim... thanks for the additional tips.  definitely useful and in line with what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The [`erl` man page`][1] shows all the command line options, but [`init(3)`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/init.html) seems to have the examples, and sometimes better descriptions. [This post](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/erlang-hello-world-example/) has some good examples as well.

Also, the options below are not mutually exclusive. The `-run`, `-s`, and `-eval` switches can be mixed.

### Option 1: `erl -run` or `erl -s`

The [`erl` man page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) describes the `-s` and `-run` switches (the
texts are the same), but the examples are in [`init(3)`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/init.html) (see blockquote below).

---

**Caveat**:
*The called module has to be compiled already, otherwise the Erlang runtime will just crash on init, producing a cryptic error message (that points to the fact that the function is undefined).*

---

> ```
> -run Mod [Func [Arg1, Arg2, ...]]
> ```
>
> Evaluates the specified function call during system initialization.
>   `Func` defaults to `start`. If no arguments are provided, the function
>   is assumed to be of arity 0. Otherwise it is assumed to be of arity 1,
>   taking the list `[Arg1,Arg2,...]` as argument. All arguments are
>   passed as strings. If an exception is raised, Erlang stops with an
>   error message.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> % erl -run foo -run foo bar -run foo bar baz 1 2
> ```
>
> This starts the Erlang runtime system and evaluates the following
>   functions:
>
> ```
> foo:start()
> foo:bar()
> foo:bar(["baz", "1", "2"]).
> ```
>
> The functions are executed sequentially in an initialization process,
>   which then terminates normally and passes control to the user. This
>   means that a `-run` call that does not return blocks further
>   processing; to avoid this, use some variant of spawn in such cases.

### Option 2: `erl -eval`

As mentioned in the section above, the module has to be compiled to be used with `-run` or `-s`, so either call `erlc` before, or add `-eval` to the mix. Assuming `amod.erl` is in the same folder where `erl` is executed

```
$ erl -eval 'compile:file(amod)' -run amod
```

This will drop to the Erlang shell prompt. See `-noshell` ([`erl` man page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html)) if only the Erlang runtime needs to be started up.

From [`init(3)`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/init.html):

> ```
> -eval Expr
> ```
>
> Scans, parses, and evaluates an arbitrary expression `Expr` during
>   system initialization. If any of these steps fail (syntax error, parse
>   error, or exception during evaluation), Erlang stops with an error
>   message. In the following example Erlang is used as a hexadecimal
>   calculator:
>
> ```
> % erl -noshell -eval 'R = 16#1F+16#A0, io:format("~.16B~n", [R])' \\
> -s erlang halt
> BF
> ```
>
> If multiple `-eval` expressions are specified, they are evaluated
>   sequentially in the order specified. `-eval` expressions are evaluated
>   sequentially with `-s` and `-run` function calls (this also in the
>   order specified). As with `-s` and `-run`, an evaluation that does not
>   terminate blocks the system initialization process.